# Loud click when playing audio in different desktop apps on an ASUS P2540 with a Conexant SmartAudio HD audio card

Tags: laptop, audio

Device is an ASUS P2540U laptop w/ Conexant SmartAudio HD audio card, running Windows 10. Looking for a fix to this issue.

A while ago, I started experiencing loud clicks when different applications play sound, when you leave your headphones on and you unplug them or turn off the computer they're plugged into. The only things that could play audio that I have open are Discord, Chrome (including several Youtube tabs), a dormant Windows Media Player window and the latest version of [Arrow Vortex](https://arrowvortex.ddrnl.com/overview.html).

5-10 minutes after the first instance it happened again when I played the chart I had open in Arrow Vortex, and a few minutes after that it happened again doing the same thing; a little while later, I clicked on the "Manage input devices" search option in Settings and it happened again, and a few moments later it happened again when I backed out of the window it opened.

A day after this, it happened again (sans the WMP window) when I played something in Arrow Vortex then tried to play something on YouTube; a few moments later I noticed a very faint click, and upon playing what was in Arrow Vortex the loud click happened again. The loud click happened again when nothing was played in Chrome. Also got another instance of the softer click thing and it happened again when switching tabs; no audio was played between this and the previous instance.

I have a hunch that this is the sound card's fault (I have a Realtek card on my home computer and this never happened there), and might be caused by different tabs. I suspect that this has something to do with the audio driver turning itself off after a while, but I know nothing about this card other than it doesn't have an EQ.

Comment: It's probably a clock mismatch [the clock signals drift until something decides it needs to drop some samples to get back in sync… click], but I've no clue how you would track that down on a PC. On a Mac you can change your clock master, I don't know of any equivalent for Windows.

Comment: is there a reason the comments were removed? We had this chat going https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111948/discussion-between-kalamalka-kid-and-helen-danger-burns

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that there is an issue with the bitrate which can easily be changed in Windows 10. If there is a control panel software

1. Right-click the Speaker icon in your system tray and click Playback devices.
2. Select your speaker, then click Properties.
3. Click the Advanced tab.
4. Click the drop-down and it will show you the sample rate and bit depths options as shown in the photo below:

[image]

5. You can adjust it according to your preference. Once done, click Apply, then OK.

## Why do I hear clicks or pops?

In complex setups, where several pieces of gear are connected digitally, sometimes clicks and pops are due to incorrect external clock settings. One device needs to provide the 'master' clock and all the others need to have their clocks set to 'external', so that they become 'slaves'. If the other devices are not locked to the master clock, you may find you hear a fairly regular ticking during normal recording and playback, while using analogue cables instead of proper S/PDIF or other digital cables may give rise to faults ranging from the occasional tick to no signal whatsoever getting through.

You can read more about clicks and pops [HERE](https://www.soundonsound.com/techniques/eradicating-pc-audio-clicks-pops)

Comment: This seems to fix my issue, but only temporarily.  Are there other options that can make it stop for longer?

Comment: Can you please resume our conversation in the chat? https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111948/discussion-between-kalamalka-kid-and-helen-danger-burns